# Play 2.3.6 - Providing FakeApplication to WithBrowser(app=...) breaks test

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm finding that integration tests using `WithBrowser` fail if I provide my own `FakeApplication`:

```scala
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class IntegrationSpec extends Specification {

  "Application" should {
    "work from within a browser" in new WithBrowser(app = FakeApplication()) { 
      browser.goTo("http://localhost:" + port)
      browser.pageSource must contain("Some text from my frontpage")
    }
  }
```

I always get a blank page:

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
  <head/>
  <body/>
</html>
' doesn't contain 'Some text from my frontpage'
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: That's strange since you're doing nothing special - if you look at the [source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Specs.scala#L48), you'll see that the default value for the `app` parameter is an instance of `FakeApplication`, just like in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the constructors of WithBrowser() I decided to try the this(...) constructor defined within the abstract class, by passing a webDriver parameter:

```
 new WithBrowser(WebDriverFactory(Helpers.HTMLUNIT), app = MyFakeApplication())
```

Turns out this is the solution. It's now working